# Is it possible to fetch Azure AAD users and groups in spark code?

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-active-directory, azure-synapse

I have a pyspark notebook in Azure Synapse where the I need to get all the Azure AAD Group along with the users in them. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Graph API will give you the list of AAD groups and group members using the following endpoints:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I built something similar to that, but using an Azure Data Factory to ingest the list of groups and group members into a storage account before using this data in Synapse.

If you prefer to implement the data ingestion in spark you can follow this link:
https://towardsdatascience.com/querying-microsoft-graph-api-with-python-269118e8180c

Comment: Thank you Diego and CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT. I was able to use graph API.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, it is not possible to fetch Azure AAD users and groups in Spark Code.

**Note:** You can use **Graph API**, **Azure CLI** and **Azure AD PowerShell** to get Azure AAD user and groups.

[image]

For more details, refer to [Azure Active Directory - Reference section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/).